# How to manage file (replace, delete...) in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I've a text file with its backup copy: backup copy has the same name with only a "2" as last character of the extension (example: Original: Myfile.txt - Backup: Myfile.txt2).
Sometimes I need to replace the original one with the backup; I do the following:

```
QFile BackupFile("Myfile.txt2");           // backup copy
QString nameFile = BackupFile.fileName();// name of backup copy of file
nameFile.chop(1);                      // remove the last letter of file name, so nameFile now is the same of Original file
QFile originalFile(nameFile);             // Original copy
originalFile.remove();                     // delete the original file
BackupFile.rename(nameFile);            // rename the backup file as original
BackupFile.close();                      // close the file
```

This works, but it seems too complex. I'd like something easier.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Why exactly do you have to rename the backup first?

Comment: You might want to open both files and copy the content of one into another, but that approach is not better than the one you use, especially in case of large files.

Answer (score 2):

I think this code can be simple method. However, you should add code for error case, such as 'check whether backup file exist.', etc..

```
auto ReplaceWithBackup = []( QString& backupName ) -> bool
{
    QString originName = backupName;
    originName.chop( 1 );

    if ( QFile::exists( originName ) )
    {
        QFile::remove( originName );
    }

    return QFile::rename( backupName, originName );
};

if ( ReplaceWithBackup( "Myfile.txt2") == false )
{
    // error
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `QString originalName = backupName;`?

Comment: I mean: auto ReplaceWithBackup = []( QString& backupName ) -> bool
Seems to be not compatible to my compiler...

Comment: I just used a lambda for readability, however you can use a normal function instead of it.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are in the same directory, you can use QDir::rename.  Otherwise reading one file and writing in the other is required. Here is my version of the first case.

```
// Generate some test data
{
    QFile bf( "Myfile.txt2" );
    bf.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    bf.write("Backup data");
    QFile( "Myfile.txt" ).open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
}

//Assume you know which back-up file to restore
QString backupFn("Myfile.txt2"); 

//Actual code
QString origFn = backupFn.mid( 0, backupFn.size()-1 ); //"guess" the original file name. 
QFile::remove( origFn );  //Use static version to delete file by name (No QFile instance required)
QDir().rename(backupFn,origFn);
```

However, each line requires many checks and validations e.g. is the provided backup-file name a valid backup name, did remove/rename succeded, etc, etc.